# Prove that $R\cong \mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x]/(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n>0$ which has $n$ distinct complex roots. Prove that $R\cong \mathbb{C}^n$.

I tried to define a homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\phi$ is onto and ker$\phi=(f(x))$. Then by first isomorphism theorem I am done. But the hard part is defining such homomorphism explicitely. First I tried to divide a given polynomial $p(x)$ by $f(x)$ and take the remainder polynomial. The remainder is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$. So it has $n$ coefficients. Then my try was mapping $p(x)$ to the $n$ tuple of those coefficients. But then I was failed proving $\phi$ is a homomorphism. So how do I determine a homomorphism explicitely? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Quotient_ring_of_K.5BX.5D

Comment: If I could read and understand what wikipedia says, I would never post this question here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i)$. The ideals $(x-\lambda_i)$ are pairwise coprime, since they are maximal and distinct. Hence, by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), we have: $$\mathbb{C}[X]/f(x)=\mathbb{C}[X]/ \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{C}[X]/ (x-\lambda_i)=\mathbb{C}^n$$

Comment: Thanks! great and simple idea!

Answer (score 9):

If the roots are $z_1, \ldots , z_n$, then one simple approach is sending $f\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ to the tuple $(f(z_1), \ldots , f(z_n))$.

It is a homomorphism on each component, therefore a homomorphism.  Using distinctness of the roots, we can calculate the kernel without too much fuss.

To show that it is surjective, count dimensions.  Alternatively, we can use Lagrange interpolation (using again the distinctness of the roots).

Comment: But I need a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta It _is_ surjective.  I've added a hint.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta By the way, _any_ homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[X]\to \mathbb{C}^n$ with kernel $(f(X))$ is surjective, by counting dimension.

Comment: Confused at the downvote, this is the most self-contained answer.

Comment: @NoahOlander I'm confused too, especially since an "explicit" homomorphism was requested.

Comment: @NoahOlander I think using Lagrange interpolation prevents it from being self-contained. The whole point of the CRT is that such a homomorphism is onto. (I have nothing to do with the downvote.)

Comment: @rschwieb I suppose that the most natural thing to do, for an elementary approach, is to calculate the kernel and then deduce surjectivity by counting dimension.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, you're right. To be honest, I think was looking for the word explicit - maybe elementary - not self-contained. It would be counterproductive to make students work to avoid using CRT in a first course on rings.